# Writing to a File in Golang

Tags: go

I'm rather new to Golang and not sure yet, how to use certain language constructs. Currently I have following code (with test debug outputs), which does not provide expected result:

```
    json, _ := json.Marshal(struct)
    fmt.Println(json)

    f,_ := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/%s.json", "asd"))

    i,_ := f.Write(json)
    fmt.Println(i)  

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    fmt.Print(b)
```

I expect the following behaviour:

- translating the struct to a byte array
- creating a new file
- append the byte array to the file

However, the file is always empty when I run the code in my environment (AWS Lambda), as well as using it in the Golang Playground.
The output of above code looks like this:

```
[123 34 ... <hug array of bytes>]
1384
[]
```

which leads me to believe I'm using `f.Write()` not correctly, although I followed the package documentation. All other outputs indicate expected behavior, so what is my mistake? I'm somewhat restricted to using the `File` interface, otherwise I'd have gone with `ioutil.WriteFile()`. My assumption is a misunderstanding of pointer/values at some point, but the compiler prevented a usage of `&f`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After `f.Write()`, your current position in the file is at the end of it, so `ioutil.ReadAll()` will read from that position and return nothing.

You need to call [`f.Sync()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Sync) to make sure that the data is persistently saved to the disk, and then [`f.Seek(0, 0)`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek) to rewind to the beginning of the file first.

Update: from comments, it seems that you only need to serialize the JSON and pass it forward as `io.Reader`, for that you don't really need a file, thanks to [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer):

```
data, _ := json.Marshal(s)
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
fmt.Print(string(b))
```

Comment: might be useful to explain what sync and seek do.

Comment: Oh wow, I would not have expected those action to be necessary. Thanks a lot, it works in both environments now! So if I do not actually save the file on disk and just pass the `File` object to another function, I can probably omit the `Sync()` and just 'rewind' the position counter.

Comment: @kopaka I am actually not quite sure how exactly it might behave without `Sync()` and whether that's platform-specific, need to check the `fsync / fseek` docs.

Comment: @bereal and for anyone wondering: it does in fact work, since I'm passing the `File` object to another function, which stores it to an S3 bucket, so there is no need ever to actually physically store the file.

Comment: @kopaka in that case you don't really need a file, check [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer).